# Is there a way to just rotate text vertically? Without rotating the whole cell?

Tags: css, vertical-text

I'm trying to do it using this:

```
.VerticalText {   
transform: rotate(-90deg); 
}
```

but it's rotating the text and cell. How do I just rotate the text vertically inside the cell?

Comment: Wrap text in `<span>` element and rotate it. The final example would be `.VerticalText span {   
transform: rotate(-90deg); 
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make a div what is outside the text, and rotate that the other way.

So: If

```
.VerticalText {  
    transform: rotate(-90deg); 
}
```

and the div outside is called for example .VerticalTextWrapper

```
.VerticalTextWrapper {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: If the cell is outside of the text, just rotate that of course..